# NuGet packages not installing "Content" to project on ASP.NET 5 RC1 (vNext) project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core

I've created a barebones ASP.NET 5 project using the latest RC1 tools on Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

I'm having a strange issue with NuGet not really acting as I've come to expect with previous versions.

In trying to install `angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped` via NuGet I expect a `Scripts\typings\angularjs` folder to be added to my project with all of the Angular TypeScript definitions.  This works perfect when using ASP.NET 4.6 but when using ASP.NET 5 nothing happens.  When I navigate to the new global NuGet packages repository at `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.dnx\packages\angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped\4.3.4` I can see the content folder that Visual Studio normally treats as content to include in your project.

I've tested this with various other packages, like Bootstrap for example, but achieved the same results.  I know you would normally use Bower for client side packages but I wanted to test something purely client side that would normally add a `"Content"` and `"Scripts"` folder.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this issue?  Or is this by design now?  And if so, what's the best way to manage this?